# ToString in .NET - missing localization option in general and on many classes

Tags: c#, .net, string, tostring

## Problem

I use a German Windows installation and therefore I occasionally stumble over something that looks like misbehaviour in .NET while dealing with string representations of objects.

Most often the underlying issue is a misbehaviour of some `ToString()` implementation within the current culture as soon as that differs from the `InvariantCulture` (= en_US).

The culture (or `CultureInfo`) encodes how numbers and dates are formatted, which language to use and more.
There are many properties of this type: Each thread has it's current culture, the UI (in WPF) has one and more.

Often the current culture is what you want when calling `ToString()` on an object, but sometimes you want to have a specific target culture - and in many cases it's not supported to choose without hacking around (see "best solution I have so far" below).

## Current State

As `System.Object` implements a basic `ToString()` many classes override it (and it's a best practice to do so as soon as there are useful information to provide beyond the class name).

Overloads of `ToString()` exist for many classes, some have an overload `ToString(CultureInfo culture)` that accepts the culture to use - but not all.

I'm pretty sure some cases are not by (chosen) design (see the Geometry class example below), but on own classes using derived `ToString()` implementations from other objects (of different types) can be challenging when you want to support localization, as there is no clean way to push the Culture down to that call.

## Example: Geometry class

Another issue I faced now was Snoop, a quite useful tool to inspect any WPF user interface of a running program.
Here I inspected a `Geometry` object, and it's `ToString()`, which - I guess - should return the mini-language that is used in XAML to easily encode the geometry, but I couldn't use the output as such, as it scrambled separators (the decimal separator `.` of en_US was replaced by the German `,`, the comma that separated the values from each other was replaced by a semicolon `;`).

There is no specification about the purpose of the ToString(), but for me it seems obvious that for the en_US culture (which I assume is the main language of Microsofts developers) Geometry.ToString() should return a "reuseable" Mini language encoding as you would use it in XAML yourself, and I cannot believe, that it's a design decision to use a similar, but unuseable encoding in other languages.

## Best solution I have so far

Having some unknown object where I want to have the string representation in a given locale the best solution I know of consists of three steps where I'm not entirely sure if they are safe to use:

```
public string ToStringWithCulture(this object self, CultureInfo targetCulture)
    var storedCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    try
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = targetCulture;
        return self.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = storedCulture;
    }
}
```

The basic principle is to switch the current culture to the desired one before, and switch back again after calling `ToString()` of the target object.

## Known or possible limitations

1. If the existing `ToString()` that is called on `self` dispatches to another thread to generate the string (not sure why any implementation should do something like that), some parts of the code might run with another "current thread culture" set, so in this case the defined current-culture doesn't work.
2. If the thread waits somewhere inside the ToString() call and another task is dispatched to this thread meanwhile, this other task might accidently get the forced `targetCulture` for it's own operations (not sure if that's the case).
3. I have no idea what the costs for switching the thread culture are - it might be expensive.

## Question(s)

1. Is this implementation safe to use, or are there limitations possible to break working code? (e.g. by switching to the wrong culture for some other thread)?
2. Is there a better way to solve this problem?
3. or: Is it necessary to extend the .NET framework APIs to support localized ToString()?

Would be happy to get some ideas,

Comment: A localized `ToString()` does _not_ belong on the base `object`, because most objects have no notion of that.  (in fact,  `ToString()` itself is quite debatable).  You're partly looking for `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, and you're confusing _display_ strings with debug or internal strings (which should _not_ use current culture)

Comment: ToString() is pretty nice in the debugger.  Using it to localize your app, well, I suppose it is possible to depend on a global variable that is not entirely under your control if you do it right.  Big changes in .NET 4.6 to make that work better, culture now flows from one thread to another.  Be sure to target it.  Read about it in the MSDN article for CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.

Comment: @SLaks well, but ToString() is mainly used for debugging purposes, and most often there's not one single string representation that fit's all use cases, so a generic ToString() on all objects for _display_ purposes is IMHO not useful at all (and except of a few simple cases I don't know many implementations where it's used for display).

Answer (score 0):

Just to address the `object.ToString` limitation:

Your approach is not too bad. However by using `IFormattable` check, you can get rid of switching the thread culture.

```
    public string ToStringWithCulture(this object self, CultureInfo targetCulture)
    {
        var formattable = self as IFormattable;

        return formattable != null ? 
            formattable.ToString(null, targetCulture) : self.ToString();
    }
```

Reflection is another option, if you want to format the ToString a bit in here.

```
    public static string ToStringWithCulture(this object self, CultureInfo targetCulture)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos  = self.GetType().GetProperties();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var prop in propertyInfos)
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(self, null) ?? "null";

            var formattable = value as IFormattable;

            var stringValue = formattable != null ? 
                formattable.ToString(null, targetCulture) : value.ToString();

            sb.AppendLine(prop.Name + " : " +stringValue);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```